# Token/stateless auth in Silex application with a Microservice architecture?

Tags: php, session, authentication, silex, microservices

I would like to use Silex as a base framework for couple of services. It would be used by different clients and apis (mobile, web etc.) so I'm generally trying to avoid cookies/session and 'do it' using headers.

Setup/flow of what I'm trying to achieve:

1. user logins in his mobile app/on webpage producing request to authservice.domain.com, gets back new token as a response which is as well registered in token store
2. when user access from web or mobile app products.domain.com the token is read from the headers and checked in store

Everything looks beautiful, but somehow I cannot make Silex add headers to requests following the login step, I'm able to add it to response, but not to request (i tried using before/after middleware so 1st auth, then add token in $app->after/before)... btw. im not sure if I understand it right, but if a user press a refresh page button when setting headers this way won't the custom header get lost? if that's the case is it possible to keep token persisted in headers without cookies/sessions after all?

Here's example code I'm running after getting token, it gets sets on response (and i can see it in chrome), but it won't get set on request - I tried as well using with before middleware

```
    $this->after(function(Request $request, Response $response) {
        $response->headers->set("X-token","2");
        $request->headers->set("X-token","2");
    });
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this? So... stateless auth using  headers over multiple services in plain (Silex : )) php without keeping token in cookies or (api gateway) sessions?

Comment: The request are sent by the client, not by the server, you read them, you cannot add data to them. You cann add data to them if you actively request something but they come from the browser mostly

Comment: Did you check the Symfony security manual? There is a tutorial on how to achieve [statless API key authentication](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/security/guard-authentication.html). There is also a [Security Provider for JWT](https://github.com/cnam/security-jwt-service-provider), which are what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it will answer your question but you could take a look at WSSE authentication mechanism, it is stateless and works with headers so it may be what your are looking for.

There is a symfony2 implementation example in the official doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html), which is also nicely explained [here](http://obtao.com/blog/2013/06/configure-wsse-on-symfony-with-fosrestbundle/).

You can find github libs which implements WSSE for Silex as well, maybe you should give them a try :

- [by alcalyn](https://github.com/alcalyn/silex-wsse)
- [by me](https://github.com/guigzz/silex-wsse)

Hope this will help you or other people looking for a way to achieve nice RESTful-ish/stateless mechanism in Silex, and sorry if it's not what your are looking for.